# 10.04 wont boot after power outage

Tags: 10.04, boot, mount, live-cd

After unexpected power outage 10.04 won't boot, the following message appears

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/***************************** on /root
failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

Busybox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) _
```

I have tried rebooting from a liveCD but it wont boot and I cannot open a terminal to try to fix it by `sudo fdisk -l`  as recommended on other posts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's message is thrown by the live CD, because it's the only way to fix it. Are you sure that the hard-drive didn't die cause of the outage ?

Comment: Try burning and booting from the [ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partedmagic/files/latest/download) of [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) and running a check of your Ubuntu partition from there.

Comment: Live cd was not giving any error message just hanging on th 'Ubuntu' screen when I tried to boot or trial without installing.
After two days or so off I powered on and it ran a disk check and asked to repair errors, after repair it booted fine, no issues.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Pat

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Ubuntu CD to do an "upgrade" in-place. Over your old OS. No data/applications should be lost.